# How to Add Jquery FullCalendar in wp plugin in admin

Tags: jquery, wordpress, fullcalendar

I m developing a plugin in my plugin file i have registers these files.

```
 function add_fullcaledar(){
            wp_enqueue_style( 'ui-css', plugins_url( '/css/jquery-ui.min.css', __FILE__ ) );
            wp_enqueue_style( 'full-css', plugins_url( '/css/fullcalendar.css', __FILE__ ) );
            wp_register_script( 'moment-js', plugins_url( '/js/moment.min.js', __FILE__ ) );
            wp_register_script( 'full-js', plugins_url( '/js/fullcalendar.min.js', __FILE__ ) );
            wp_enqueue_script('moment-js');
            wp_enqueue_script('full-js');
 }
 add_action('admin_head', array( $this,'add_fullcaledar'));
```

In my admin i have loaded a page Calendar where i have coded these lines.

```
<div id="calender">
          </div>

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    



          var calendar = jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            editable: true,
            header: {
             left: 'prev,next today',
             center: 'title',
             right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            }

    }); 


  });
```

But no error is occurring nor its giving me any error .

Comment: So, the problem is that you don't see the calendar? Have you added a `<div id='calendar'></div>` somewhere in the template?

Comment: I have added that . Its still not working

Comment: Are you sure you get no messages on the javascript console of your browser when opening that admin page?

Comment: yeah I have checked many times .

Comment: I'm not a wordpress expert, but maybe adding some details to your question could help people that are, i'd recommend to add: 1- the name of the php file that you modified, 2: it's not clear *where* you added that stuff,  add some lines or specify more clearly where you added those piece of code