# How to add Jquery full Calendar Plugin in wordpress admin

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins, fullcalendar

I have added these file in my plugin .

```
function  fullcalendar(){
        wp_enqueue_style( 'full-css', 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.3/fullcalendar.min.css' );
        wp_register_script( 'js','https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js' );
        wp_register_script( 'moment-js','http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js' );
        wp_register_script( 'ui-js','http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"' );
        wp_register_script( 'full-js', 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.1.1/fullcalendar.min.js' );
        wp_enqueue_script('js');
        wp_enqueue_script('moment-js');
        wp_enqueue_script('ui-js');
        wp_enqueue_script('full-js');
    }
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', array( $this,'fullcalendar'));
```

this my page code

```
 <div id="calender" >
          </div>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 

    jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Currently its not giving me any error nor its giving required result .

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Add Jquery FullCalendar in wp plugin in admin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31263409/how-to-add-jquery-fullcalendar-in-wp-plugin-in-admin)

Comment: yeah .But i didnt get my answer

Comment: Hey Hassan, we can only guess what's wrong here, you have minimal information so try to add more information like @uraimo suggested as comment on your other question. Asking another same question is not helping and definitely not speeding up the process.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is most likely the spelling error in your div id-tag. The id is **"calender"** while your selector in the javascript is **"calendar"**.